# Volume of a polytope cut off by a hyperplane

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Given a maximization problem with constraints, and adding a few more constraints using the Gomory cuts and solving the relaxed maximization problem, we can arrive at integer solutions. I am looking to choose the cuts based on the volume that it cuts. Is there a way to determine it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is essentially the same as asking - how do you compute the volume of a polytope? If I understand this correctly, you want to choose a cut based on how much of the linear relaxation it cuts off yes? So then all you're doing is forming a new polytope by taking the intersection of the half-space defined by the cut with the linear relaxation polytope (which presumably is already given to you as an intersection of half spaces).

This has been discussed before in [this thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/979/algorithm-for-finding-the-volume-of-a-convex-polytope).

However I have to ask why you want to do this. Computing volumes on polytopes is not in general an easy task. So I doubt you'd gain much computationally compared to simply adding all the cuts to the LP relaxation and resolving. You have to generate the cutting planes to compare them anyway right? And I have a feeling any numerical instability argument will also apply to the volume computation (not sure about this though).